# Reference Request - Fubini's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Where can I find a straight-forward proof of Fubini's theorem for the Lebesgue integral on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: The only proof I sort of remember is via Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem. I found this on a brief google https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4400/h15/product-measure-12oct2015.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Stein-Shakarchi's *Princeton Lecture Series in Analysis III* has a good proof.

Some probability books do a quicker job via the use of more auxiliary results. Jacob Rosenthal's *First look at Rigorous Probability* would be my rec.

Wheeden and Zygmund's *Measure and Integral* is a classic text.

I'd comment that proofs of Fubini's Theorem tend to be lengthy in nature. As far as "straight-forward" is concerned, I'd say the lengthier proofs also tend to be more direct which may be what you want when you say "straight-forward"?